# using x11 emacs in mountain lion

Tags: macos, emacs, x11, macports, osx-mountain-lion

I have been trying to use macport's installation by using sudo port install emacs +x11 on my laptop with mountain lion, but every time I open emacs in terminal, it opens in the terminal without any GUI. This also happens if I try to open emacs directly in an xquartz terminal session. Has anyone had any luck with installing the x11 version of emacs on mountain lion? And if so, how? Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure your PATH is set correctly? Are you sure that you are calling your newly built emacs executable and not just the one that came with OS X?

Comment: I double checked using `which emacs` and the path is to /opt/local/bin/emacs which should be the macports. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: please consider editing question and answer (which you can accept) to make everything clear without having to read the comments ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out apple cut the link between terminal and xquartz. If I open emacs in xterm, it will run just fine. I found this to be the case even when I was using terminal with an ssh server. Looks like apple's terminal isn't going to be all that helpful from here on out.

Edit; I'm not sure if it was an update to xQuartz, but the problem has been fixed. When I type in an x11 app into the normal terminal app, it will open xQuartz as normal.

Comment: Are you sure? It works for me. Make sure your `DISPLAY` environment variable is set correctly.

Comment: After a while of searching I typed `export DISPLAY=":0"` into terminal and it worked! UPDATE; only works if xquartz is already open

Comment: It seems like my issue mostly has to do with Terminal being able to open xquartz